Power Apps Patch truncating at 55 rows
Power app patch issue.
Have a gallery with 3 fields with a simple patch to SharePoint list:
ForAll(
    Filter(
        IS2_Gallery1.AllItems,
        !(IS2_Checkbox_Delete.Checked)
    ),
    Patch(
        'OBC Stage Table',
        Defaults('OBC Stage Table'),
        {
            _SourceAlt: ThisRecord.IS2_TI_SourceAlt1.Text,
            _DestAlt: ThisRecord.IS2_TI_DestAlt1.Text,
            _ExactCross: ThisRecord.IS2_TI_ExactCross1.Text,
            _SubmitEmail: useremail,
            _SubmitName: username
        }
    )
);

The IS2_gallery1.Items is straightforward:
Filter(colInternalProcessed,!IsBlank(SourceAlt))
Problem is it only patches the first 55 rows of gallery data. Exactly 55 rows, then it patches blank values.
I've tried different data sets, patching to a dataverse table, rebuilding the sharepoint list, always the same, 55 rows and then nothing. I've tried scrolling though the gallery to the bottom, looked at the data within the collection to see if there's anything odd going on, the data is there in both collection and the gallery view.
I did up the delegation in settings to 2000, but not even coming close with the gallery size and it truncates at 55 rows.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Are you updating/storing checkbox check/uncheck value in your collection (colInternalProcessed)? If yes, can you try using ForAll based on collection instead of IS2_Gallery1.AllItems? Let me know if this works for you.

The checkbox is items the user decided to not add, so those get filtered out before patching.
The starting function is ForAll, with the utilized array being the filtered IS2_Gallery1.AllItems

I did remove the filter of the checkbox and ran without that, still truncates the 56th row on.

If colInternalProcessed and IS2_Gallery1.AllItems has same data/records, try using forall on collection instead of gallery items.

The gallery is present so the user can make last minute changes to the data before final write/patch, so it might not be the same data.


Gallery source must be a collection
When the user checks/unchecks, add a function on it's onchecked and onunchecked trigger to update that item in the collection itlself.
Run your ForAll function on the Collection itself.
The problem that you are experiencing is most likely because gallery loads 100 items by default and as the user scrolls beyond the 100 items, the gallery loads the next 100 items.
Try the above steps and it'll get sorted.

